# BlueImp Carousel - TypeError this.slides[t] is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, blueimp

I followed the official [setup guide](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#carousel-setup) of blueimp.

I downloaded the latest version of blueImp (2.25.0)

First I included the css and js:

```
<!-- Blueimp Gallery -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/Gallery-2.25.0/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">

<script src='../public/Gallery-2.25.0/js/blueimp-gallery.min.js'></script>
```

Then I prepared the carousel:

```
<div id="blueimp-gallery-carousel" class="image blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls blueimp-gallery-carousel">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
```

Now I prepared the pictures:

```
<div id="links">

    <a href="../pcs/pic1.png"></a>
    <a href="../pcs/pic2.png"></a>
    <a href="../pcs/pic3.png"></a>

</div>
```

At last I included a script:

```
<script src="../js/blueImp.js"></script>
```

...with the following content:

```
<script>
blueimp.Gallery(
    document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('a'),
    {
        container: '#blueimp-gallery-carousel',
        carousel: true
    }
);
</script>
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see I followed the setup guide, however I get **TypeError: this.slides[t] is undefined** after clicking on an arrow. I also tried it with 2.23.0, same error.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Test Browsers:**

Mozilla Firefox 52.0.2 (64-Bit), Mozilla for Ubuntu

Mozilla Firefox 52.0.1 (32-Bit), Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by wrapping the script at the bottom with Jquerys `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

            blueimp.Gallery(
                document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('a'),
                {
                    container: '#blueimp-gallery-carousel',
                    carousel: true
                }
            );
        });
```

I don't understand why this was necessary though, since the script was included at the very last position, just before the closing body tag. Any explanation?